# Warning in IDE: Tage h:commandLink is unknown

Tags: jsf, xhtml

My problem is that I cannot invoke bean's method from the menu.
When I do below way, the page doesn't show the Logout as hlink, but after loading logout is already fired, I see it in the logs. The same is with `onclick`.
I tried `h:commandLink`, but then the page aren't rendered at all, also IDE shows that the tag `h:commandLink` is unknown. What am I doing wrong?
I need to populate logout as a link, not as a button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>     
<body>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="header">
                    <h1>Test</h1>
                    <h2>test</h2>
                </div>
                <div id="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#{loginBean.logout}">logout</a></li>

                    </ul>
                    <b>Welcome, #{loginBean.userName}</b>
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: I recommend to take a pause and work through a decent JSF book first. This is already covered in chapter 1. You can find some book recommendations at https://jsf.zeef.com

Comment: You are right, I'm already doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h:commandLink action = "#{loginBean.userName}>
```

It will work. I think h:commandLink is unknown because you forget to declare the h tag at the top of the xhtml page. This h tag contains JavaServer Faces component tags for all UIComponent + HTML RenderKit Renderer combinations defined in the JavaServer Faces Specification.

Comment: `<li class="menuitem"><h:commandLink action = "#{loginBean.userName}">logout</h:commandLink></li>` Doesn't work, still warning. If I deploy war, the page is not rendered at all. Could you elaborate how to declare tag at the top of xhtml? I edited the starting post to show the top.

Comment: I don't know what you want to do with h tag but as i know is h tag is a special tag for jsf and it's written in xhtml. So, I think you will need these two link.
**xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"**
**xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"**

Comment: Now it works! Please add this comment as an answer, I will mark it as a solution. Thanks a lot!